# Override site's registration restriction on accepting invite

Tags: 8, users

We have a custom module that uses the invite module to send invitation to non users. Our site is set to allow registration only by administrator to avoid spam. When the invitees accept the invite they cannot register as its not allowed by the site. Is there a way to override registration restriction when invitees try to register?

We are looking into duplicating registration form on another route then routing the invitees to register there instead of default route.

Any other suggestions to handle this situation?

Comment: We can now instantiate the registration form on a custom route, but we need a way to override if the site restricts registration by admin only, or requires admin approval, or requires email verification. Any suggestion how site configuration can be overridden on registration form on a custom route.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but it could be done with the following:

> - my_website.com/admin/config/people/accounts
>
>   - Who can register accounts? - Visitors
> - Install https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect and add redirect `/user/register` to a basic page which says something like "Sorry, to register you need an invite. Please contact us to receive an invite."

Invited people can now log in to site but there is no way for people to access the user register page, as that page will redirect.

Comment: We need a more flexible solution, when chosen by the admin the regular registration restrictions can be overridden.